# How can I clear all transactions for a PeopleSoft Approval Process? Using SQL

Tags: peoplesoft

New to AWE. I have a situation where data and/or configuration and/or code has become "broken" or scrambled or corrupted while building this approval process.

I'd like to clear out all stuck transactions and start again.

*Monitor Approvals* has the status for all approval process as status = 'Approved'. They are not. So, I'd like to just clear out all the transaction data and start again.

Which tables do I need to clear out (update and/or delete)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that since AWE is (for now) built on top of plain, old Workflow I was able to get myself out of trouble by simply updating the Worklist items' status to approved for the user, and clearing the header and XREF tables:

```
update psworklist set inststatus = 3 where oprid='TheUser';
delete from ps_your_xref;
delete from ps_your_header_rec;
```

Warning: This might well be a very cowboy approach, has worked fine for me **in Development**.